# repeat putting input element randomly between user's text

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a text element that is built when the user clicks a button. In the middle of that text, I added an input element.I want to make this process repeats seven times but it looks complicated. I actually made a lot of things but here are the important ones So, First I made an input element and a button when the user enter input and click the button what he wrote will be displayed in a h1 element with a random missing word Then,I made an input element in the that the missing word should've been in.What I want is that this to repeat this process seven times.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  x = x + " ";
  var y = document.getElementById("inputed");
  var a,b = "c";
  const c=[];
  const d=[];
  var e;
  var f = 0;
  const array = [];
  const z = x.length;
  for (let index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
    a= "c";
    b= "c";
    c.push(0);
    d.push(0);
    c[index] = 0;
    d[index] = 0;
    e = 1;
    f = 0;
    //Here the program will get a random space location and the space after it
    while (a != " ") {
      c[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length - 2);
      a = x.charAt(c[index]);
    }
    d[index] = c[index];
    //The variable d will be the same as c and will increase until its value corrspends to a space
    while (b != " ") {
      d[index]++;
      b = x.charAt(d[index]);
    }
    //I want the y.innerHTML to write from the 0 to c[0] then display the input element then from d[0] //to c[1] and display the input element again and form d[1] to c[2] until 7
    y.innerHTML = `${x.slice(
      0,
      c[0]
    )}<input type="text" style="color: gray;border:2px solid;border-radius: 10px;outline: none;
font-size: x-large;height:40px;width: 100px;" >${x.slice(d[0], z)} `;
  }
}
```

Comment: the very first thing I can see wrong in your code is how you declare variables. Please avoid using the `,` notation because not only it affects readability but you should know how it works first. If you do `let a, b=[]` only `b` will be initialized with an empty array. Then make the effort to give a proper name to variables and try to better factor your logic so that it's not everything stuffed in one statement. Those are just friendly suggestions for you to more easily deal with this kind of task

Comment: Thanks!When I opened my website after the changements that I made there was no text but with your help it was fixed.Now the arrays a and b work fine but the problem is how to add  the input element to text seven times

Comment: your words show you are not getting a single word of what I'm saying. `a` and `b` was just an example and your arrays were actually `c` and `d` That code is a huge mess with no meaning.  If you maybe better rephrase your question to make it more clear someone will get exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry I litrally meant c and d honest mistake

Comment: So what I want to do is make the y text display first x.slice(0,c[0]) then the input element then x.slice(d[0],c[1]) then the same input element then x.slice(d[1],c[2]) then the same input element until it reacher x.slice(d[7],z) I hope you understood now

Comment: it's not clear why your code is so convoluted; it's not clear what your code is trying to do; it's not clear why you have variables like `a,b,c,d,x,y`... instead of giving them a meaningful name; it's not clear what's the role of `y` (`#inputed`); it's not clear why you loop an array starting from -1; it's not clear why you push  a new item in an array AND you also set the current index at zero; it's not clear why you repeat the same operation on two different arrays...

Comment: I have several question for each single line of that code. I suggest you to just explain with clear words what  you expected to do with that code because it will be easier than spending a lifetime to decode what it wished to do but couldnt

Comment: Ok! I edited the code because it has some problems. So What this program should do is recieve text from the user and rewrite it in the y element and delete a random word and replace with an input element.First, I made the c array get a random value between 0 and the text length and the text is x and if its x.charAt is a space then the while loop ends and then i made the array d increases until its x.charAt is also a space so the characters between the c first element and the d first element are the word that I want to delete then the index increases and the same process will repeate

Comment: When this proccess repeats I need to save the space before and after the random word that is why I made c and d arrays so when the loop repeats I used push to save what I need in a new slot in this arrays. I hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems understanding perfectly your code so I couldn't answer trying to address the exact problems affecting your specific algorithm.

Anyway I made an attempt trying to understand your description and as far as I could get I tried to implement a demo beginning from a input text filled by the user and:

- When the button PARSE SENTENCE gets clicked, the procedures parses the
  input text splitting its content by white spaces to find out the
  words.
- Then it determines how many random words he wants to "remove" from
  the string and at which index.
- Then it creates a `span` element for each of those words and put all of them
  in a separate array
- Such spans, will have the word in their innerText, the default class
  `word` and an added class that will be `kept-word` if that's a word not
  to remove and `removed-word` otherwise. Plus they will keep track of that original word inside a data attribute called `data-original`
- Those spans get appended to the `#transformed` element, and at this
  stage, if the word belongs to the class `.removed-word` its
  `innerText` gets emptied and its `contenteditable` attribute
  activated.
- In the end, after the parsing of the sentence, the exact spans code
  will be shown in the `<pre>` element to give evidence of what's going
  on

I know it's very far from what you have asked.. considering I didn't strictly stressed the algorithm aspect and mostly used shortcut like `split`, `includes`, `contains` and more importantly I totally changed your logics and used `span`s for words parsed and didn't use the `input` at all but `contenteditable`.

***I sincerely hope it will anyway give some inspiration***

```js
function transform(){

  const input = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
  const words = input.split(" ");
  const nrOfWordsToReplace = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  const indexesOfWordsToReplace
    = Array.from({length: nrOfWordsToReplace}, () => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
      });  

  //for each word in the input, create a span element to add in #transformed
  //words expected to be kept will have their span with class .word.kept-word
  //words expected to be removed will have their span with class .word.remove-word
  let index = 0;
  const outputWords = [];
  for(word of words){
    if( indexesOfWordsToReplace.includes(index) ){
        const outputWord = createOutputWordElement(word, 'removed-word');
        outputWords.push( outputWord );
    }else{
        const outputWord = createOutputWordElement(word, 'kept-word');
        outputWords.push( outputWord );
    }
    index++;
  }
  
  const codeContainer = document.querySelector('pre');
  codeContainer.innerHTML = '';

  //clear its content appends those spans to #transform
  const transformed = document.getElementById('transformed');
  transformed.innerHTML = '';
  for(outputWord of outputWords){
    if (outputWord.classList.contains('removed-word')){
      outputWord.innerText = '';
      outputWord.contentEditable = true;
    }
    transformed.append(outputWord);
    
    const code = document.createElement('code');
    code.innerText = outputWord.outerHTML;
    codeContainer.append(code);
  }  
}

//returns a span element having the word as content and classname among its classes
function createOutputWordElement(word, classname){
  const outputWord = document.createElement('span');
  outputWord.classList.add('word');
  outputWord.classList.add(classname);
  outputWord.dataset.original = word;
  outputWord.innerText = word;
  
  return outputWord;
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 1rem;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#input{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

pre code{
  display: block;
}
#transformed{
  border: dashed 3px darkgray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.word{
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: .25rem;
  margin-right: .50rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.word.kept-word{
  border-color: darkgray;
}

.word.removed-word{
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 2rem;
}
.
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">

<button type="button" onclick="transform();">Parse sentence</button>

<div id="transformed"></div>

<pre>
</pre>
```